# Invoke-WebRequest and client certificate chain

Tags: powershell, client-certificates

I'm trying to send a request to an endpoint. I need to present a client certificate and this was working until the endpoint was changed to only have the root CA in the trusted list (before it had the intermediate as well).

I was told that I needed to make sure the full chain is sent (which i'm) and that I also needed to move from "Invoke-WebRequest" to curl.

> "The existing method for invoking web-requests
> (Invoke-WebRequest) does not properly present the client certificate
> incl. the full certficate chain.
>
> In order to be able to consume API endpoints protected by a client
> certificate from Powershell, the existing command Invoke-WebRequest
> needs to be replaced using CURL"

Given the fact that this will force me to do more than I would like, I would like to know if anyone had this issue before and was able to make it work anyway without the CURL.

```
$certificate = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2
$certificate.Import($certificateFilePath, $certificatePassword,'DefaultKeySet')

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Method 'PUT' -Headers @{ 'Authorization' = $accessToken ; 'api-version' = $apiVersion;  'Content-Type' = $contentType } -Body $body -Certificate $certificate
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? It seems as though your code works but you want to find a way to do it in fewer steps? That wasn't clear to me when I tried to figure out what you need from the community.